# What is the reason behind AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'?

Tags: python, tkinter

Error Trace:

```
_cnfmerge: fallback due to: 'int' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Untitled.py", line 25, in <module>
    app = AddFrame(master=root, title=titleres, width=400)
  File "/Users/.../Untitled.py", line 8, in __init__
    Frame.__init__(self, master, width)   #height error gives need only 
3 arguments , 4 given find out    Frame.__init__(self, master, width, height, bg)TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2561, in __init__
            cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 119, in _cnfmerge
        for k, v in c.items():
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

My code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import datetime
class AddFrame(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, master=None, title = "default_title", width=400, height=400, bg='blue') :
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width) 

         self.grid()
         self.master.title(title)

root = Tk()
root.title('Skeleton Test 1')
root.geometry('1920x1080')



ffcu0 = Frame(root, bg='blue', width=1080, height=700)
ffcu1 = Frame(root, bg='red', width=1080, height = 480)
ffcu2 = Frame(root, bg='green', width=270, height = 700)
ffcu3 = Frame(root, bg='blue', width=270, height = 480)
titleres='research'
app = AddFrame(master=root, title=titleres, width=400)


ffcu0.grid(row=0, column=0)
ffcu1.grid(row=2, column=0)
ffcu2.grid(row=0, column=1)
ffcu3.grid(row=2, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tk.Frame` expects its arguments as named options. Try `tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master, width=width)`

Answer (score 4):

`width` is a keyword only argument. You have to supply it as `width=width`.

```
class AddFrame(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, master=None, title = "default_title", width=400, height=400, bg='blue') :
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=width)
```

All initialization arguments for tkinter widgets are keyword only, except `self` and `master`.

Comment: _"All tkinter arguments"_ that's mostly true, but not completely true if by "all tkinter arguments" refers to all tkinter classes and methods.